# Does OAuth2 verify the request domain via http headers?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am currently learning about OAuth2, and I am slightly confused about one part of it. Does the OAuth2 server compare the domain in the JWT with the domain in the request header?

What prevents someone from ripping a bearer token out of a JS app and then using it to make fraudulent API requests? Even if HTTPS is used, the token sent back from OAuth2 still has to be stored before it can be used in subsequent requests, thus making it vulnerable. What am I missing?

Edit: what if I create an oauth2 token from a non-browser client and there is no domain name to match against?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents it from being used. That's why you store it safely or you don't store it at all.

Comment: That's not true. From what I have learned so far, you can store the token and just make it expire after one use, limit what resources it can access, or possibly verify the IP of the client. There is no way to secure the bearer token in a js app. But to answer my own question, no, OAuth does not check the domain of those that request bearer tokens.

Comment: Yes, all those are possible. The expiration is a way of limiting risk. But while valid, tokens can be reused if you just check exp. I haven't see one-time uses of JWT (compared to code for the authz_code flow as an example). IP checks are app specific validations, not part of OAuth.